# What is the use of RMISecurityManager?

Tags: java, rmi

I keep getting the answer that it is used by apps that use downloaded code. What does downloaded code here means?? And what is the main use of RMISecurityManager in computer networks in simple words??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Downloaded code” means code that has been transferred from a remote site to the local JVM, see [RMIClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/rmi/server/RMIClassLoader.html) Since this option has some risks, `RMIClassLoader` will refuse to work unless a `SecurityManager` has been installed.

But:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/rmi/RMISecurityManager.html

> RMISecurityManager implements a policy that is no different than the policy implemented by SecurityManager. Therefore an RMI application should use the SecurityManager class or another application-specific SecurityManager implementation instead of this class.

Sounds like that particular class `RMISecurityManager` is obsolete, at least in current version of the JRE. Any other `SecurityManager` will do.